# Multiple returns of different data types

Tags: java, return

I'm completely lost and getting desperate.
I'm working with Netbeans and what I'm trying to do is just have 2 or more variable of different types be sent to one class, be modified at that location, and then all be returned to the starting location along with the modifications they went under.
I can't put them into an array because in this instance I'm using an Integer and a Double and in the actual code I'm using a lot more than just 2 variables.

```
public class Passing_Objects {

public void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 5;
    double b = 10;
    ? = Extra.Carry(a, b);
    System.out.println("A = " + a + ", B = " + b);
}    

class Extra {

public int a;
public double b;

public Extra(int _a, double _b) {
    this.a= _a;
    this.b= _b;
    return ?;
}
```

Either what I'm looking for can't be done or my feeble incompetent mind is too stupid to comprehend the solution everyone else is using.
Either way I can't make any progress in my code unless I solve this problem.
Could someone please help me understand what I need to do and would the solution be any different if variables A or B were arrays?

Comment: Please tag your question with the language you are using.

Comment: Sorry, using Netbeans IDE 7.4. Forgot about that part.

Comment: Netbeans is a program (an integrated development environment... that's what IDE means). You are writing a Java program

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
public class Passing_Objects {

public void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 5;
    double b = 10;
    Extra extra = new Extra(a, b);
    System.out.println("A = " + extra.getA() + ", B = " + extra.getB());
}    

class Extra {

public int a;
public double b;

public Extra(int a, double b) {
    this.a= a;
    this.b= b;
}

public int getA(){
return a;
}

public double getB(){
return b;
}
}
}
```

**Edit** :
To alter the values after a first initialization, you need setters.

Something like these two methods in your Extra class.

```
public void setA(int a){
this.a = a;
}

public void setB(double b){
this.b = b;
}
```

then in your Passing-Objects class, you can set new values by invoking the setter methods.

```
extra.setA(20); 

extra.setB(20d);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Something like that. But say that in the beginning Integer a = 5 but later on I want Integer a to equal 20 and the same for Double b? How do I get them to be something different from what they started as?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention this, but the general idea is that in one area of the code a and b or initiated and later on in the code, in this case Extra, would alter a and b in different ways and the changes would stay.
It seems so easy to do but I feel too stupid to see the correct technique to accomplish this.

Comment: You need setters. I will put some example in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really bad at this. I understand what you're saying with the setter, I actually didn't know that, but now I don't know where to put it.

Comment: i.e : use the setters in your main method after the print out. What do you want to do ?..

Comment: Well it's just an text RPG I'm making with my friends and that the code uses multiple classes to make everything organized and smaller than one massive class over 20,000 lines long.
And basically a While function keeps all the classes working in a giant loop, but when it reaches the last class and brings everything back to the top to be recorded and altered again all the changes are lost. Basically one variable will go through 5 or 6 classes as 5 and then at the end of the last will be altered to 10 and brought back, but then the changes are lost.

Comment: So then the output statement should just look like this right? Or something like this?

    System.out.println("A = " + extra.setA());

Comment: Sorry I seem so pathetic at all of this. I learned a bit in high school a couple years, but that was pretty much the basics. Everything I've done up until now has been self-taught and that's only really the stuff I need.

Comment: So sorry about this, but were were I to do if I were sending an array as well? Like if I were to send an Integer array of C from the main to the Extra and have it change in Extra like A and B did?

Comment: You will do exactly the same way. Declare an array C as a field, and implement its setter and getter in class Extra.

Comment: So the Extra class will say:  
for (int d = 0; d < 3; d++){  
this.d[e] = this.d[e] + 1;  
}  
  
And then for the Main class will it look something like this?  
extra.setD();

Comment: No sorry, I think you really need to re-learn the basics of OOP and Java. Its much more simpler. You can't just guess. Just learn , then try.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for getting me this far. It's been a lot of help.